# How to create a data folder for my application?

Tags: java, android, file, download, outputstream

I wrote this code for downloading some files in my android application but now downloaded files are in the root without any special order and it looks very bad! So I want to know how can I add a folder for my application's downloaded files?

A code line to explain the path of output :

```
 OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + downloadedfileName);
```

And here is my code:

```
private class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private String downloadedfileName;
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "بارگذاری...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DownloadActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("کتاب در حال بارگذاري، لطفا منتظر بمانيد...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pDialog.dismiss();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DownloadActivity.this)
            .setTitle("دانلود کتاب با موفقیت انجام شد")
            .setMessage("از دانلود شما  سپاس‌گذاریم.")
            .setNeutralButton("خواهش میکنم", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(DownloadActivity.this, LibActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    DownloadActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                    DownloadActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
        }
        public void setDownloadedFileName(String downloadedfileName){
            this.downloadedfileName = downloadedfileName;
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... surl) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(surl[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100%
                // progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream
                //OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                //        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                //        + "/data/" + downloadedfileName);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ketabha/" + downloadedfileName);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    // publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't create a folder in external storage on android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387252/cant-create-a-folder-in-external-storage-on-android-device)

Comment: @mvillar no dear I have that permission in my manifest. tank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as simple change this to your favorite directory:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ANYFOLDER/ANOTHERFOLDER/" + downloadedfileName);
```

And remember that in the first create that directory with this code:

```
File dir = new File(yourdirectory);
if(!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Above code work if you added related manifest in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and for more information see below links:

[How to create directory automatically on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

[Create folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794974/create-folder-in-android)

[can't create a folder in external storage on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387252/cant-create-a-folder-in-external-storage-on-android-device)

Comment: thank you for answering. I changed that path but it didn't work!

Comment: @NiloofarHakkaki How to added it? please provide your complete code? I suggested you make directory first in `onPreexecute` method.

Comment: I am downloading files in the root so you know I have all permissions in manifest.

Comment: is that you want me to do: ?
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ketabha/" + downloadedfileName);

Comment: Do added `ketabha` directory programmaticaly? and what is your exception or logcat?

Comment: I edited my question with complete code. it just doesn't make folder after downloading file and I have to use root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65526/discussion-between-naruto-uzumaki-and-niloofar-hakkaki).

Comment: tank you for every thing.

Comment: It should be `dir.mkdirs()`. Given the example certainly.