# Creating an internal folder in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a folder in android to store files concerning the user of the application.

I created an input output utility class for the use of the application.

For the moment i wrote this:

```
public void createFolder(){

    String dirPath =  new String();
    dirPath  =  getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyFolder";
    File folder = new File(dirPath);

    if(!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
        Log.i("IO", ""+folder.exists());
    }

}
```

But when i try and call it from the main activity i get a null pointer exception:
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getFilesDir()' on a null object reference"

I know what is a null object reference but i don't understand which part of my code cause it.

Comment: Have a look at these: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387252/cant-create-a-folder-in-external-storage-on-android-device) and that [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794974/create-folder-in-android).

Comment: `NullPointerException` !!! Which context is used by your utility class? If there is no context your code should not compile. From which class is it derived?

Comment: `folder.mkdir();
        Log.i("IO", ""+folder.exists());`. That is nonsense. You shoul check the return value of mkdirs() before you tell that the folder is created. It might fail! Use mkdirs() instead of mkdir().

Comment: @greenapps i found the error, there was nos context, the code could still compile though. As for that line, i used it to check if the mkdir was created, i shouldn't have used the Log for that i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add permission in manifest.xml

```
<manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

[Save Files on Device Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: Those permissions are not needed for `getFilesDir()`.